# Direct to S3 with client-side validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

We are using [s3_file_field](https://github.com/sheerun/s3_file_field) to upload videos directly to S3, and we are planning on using [client side validations](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) to make sure the uploads are within our size restrictions, but I'm worried that a hacker might be able to turn JS off, and upload a 500GB file to our S3 bucket.

In the past, whenever I've used client-side validations, I've also had server-side validations backing them up, so I've never been too concerned about users turning JS off, but we can't have server-side validations here as we're going directly to S3.

How easy is it for a hacker to get around client side validations? Is it just a case of turning JS off? Would it help if we disabled our upload form when JS is disabled?

Should we be implementing a worker or observer to sweep uploaded videos, and run validations on them sometime after they've been uploaded, and before they can be accessed by users?

Comment: AFAIK user should have public and secret keys for file upload. So if you give it to user he can just open javascript, copy the keys and upload what he want without any validations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any maximum file upload size constraints that you can place on an S3 bucket, per se. As far as I can find, there aren't any AWS policy provisions for that.

But S3 supports [CORS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html), which is what `s3_file_field` uses to make this direct upload work. If S3 supports the `content-length-range` policy element of CORS, you can add that and then are probably covered.

Also [s3_file_field](https://github.com/sheerun/s3_file_field) is actually an extension of [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), and that has various validation options, including `max_file_size` as [documented here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#maxfilesize). In `s3_file_field` the default `max_file_size` is 500 megabytes and it appears [you can override it](https://github.com/sheerun/s3_file_field/blob/501b73e373e2810572404a583caf38f0c0fd2874/lib/s3_file_field/form_helper.rb#L39).

Either way, if a user disables javascript, then they won't be able to run JQuery File Upload, which means they shouldn't be able to upload anything at all via CORS.

Just make sure you specify the `AllowedOrigin` in production, as stated in the `s3_file_field` docs.

Answer (score 1):

The client side size check can of course be overwritten. However whenever you do a straight to s3 upload there is a policy document (signed with your aws credentials) specifying what is allowed and is not allowed.

In particular you can set limits on the file size. It looks like `s3_file_field` sets that up properly so  even if someone circumvents the client side check, s3 would reject the upload because it wouldn't match the policy.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great relief to know we're covered by the policy document.